# Why do I see a blank screen instead of my fragment in my Andoird App?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I have a `MainActivity` as the entry point to my app. The corresponding `activity_mail.xml` contains a `FragmentContainerView` (I've also tried replacing that with a simple `fragment`) which is the `NavHostFragment`

Now, I have a `fragment_dashboard.xml` which I inflate to be shown inside the `MainActivity`. I've also verified that the `fragment` is actually inflated by putting `Toast` messages.

The problem is: **The app loads a blank screen instead of `fragment_dashboard.xml`**

Please see the screenshots and codes for the full details.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screens.MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**fargment_dashboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".screens.DashboardFragment">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierMargin="8dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
        app:contentPadding="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <include layout="@layout/progress_row" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="For Testing Purposes Only"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

[Navigation graph correctly renders the xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXp4o.png)

[This is the running app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRwrr.jpg)

**Update**
I discovered that when I rotate the screen, the layout appears, and with any consecutive rotaition everything is fine. But, why is the layout invisible at first?

These are some logs I recorded:

```
2021-08-12 03:51:06.427 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/ActivityLifecycleTrack: Activity OnCreate
2021-08-12 03:51:06.463 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/FragmentLifecycleTrack: Fragment OnCreateView
2021-08-12 03:51:06.498 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/FragmentLifecycleTrack: Fragment OnViewCreated
2021-08-12 03:51:06.499 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/FragmentLifecycleTrack: Fragment OnActivityCreated
2021-08-12 03:51:06.505 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/FragmentLifecycleTrack: Fragment onStart
2021-08-12 03:51:06.513 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/FragmentLifecycleTrack: Fragment onResume
```

Up to this point, nothing visible. Fron here on (after the first rotation), the layout appears.

```
2021-08-12 03:51:28.077 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/FragmentLifecycleTrack: Fragment onPause
2021-08-12 03:51:28.081 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/FragmentLifecycleTrack: Fragment onStop
2021-08-12 03:51:28.092 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/FragmentLifecycleTrack: Fragment onDestroyView
2021-08-12 03:51:28.095 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/FragmentLifecycleTrack: Fragment onDestroy
2021-08-12 03:51:28.215 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/ActivityLifecycleTrack: Activity OnCreate
2021-08-12 03:51:28.268 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/FragmentLifecycleTrack: Fragment OnCreateView
2021-08-12 03:51:28.294 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/FragmentLifecycleTrack: Fragment OnViewCreated
2021-08-12 03:51:28.295 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/FragmentLifecycleTrack: Fragment OnActivityCreated
2021-08-12 03:51:28.299 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/FragmentLifecycleTrack: Fragment onStart
2021-08-12 03:51:28.308 11553-11553/ir.newsha.billionairesteam I/FragmentLifecycleTrack: Fragment onResume
```

Comment: Use layout inspector. And there might be some issue with constraints so test with the values as `match_parent` for fragment Container view instead of 0dp

Comment: @KamalNayan Thank you my friend, but changing constraints to match_parent didn't remedy that. In fact, in Layout Preview everything looks fine. In the app itself, however, the fragment is blank

Comment: The Toolbar and BottomNavigationView are both missing app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent". That may not be the cause of the problem, but worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Bottom nav view

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />     <--- this is missing in your code
```

Your MainActivity should look like this: (Kotlin)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);

    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.DashboardFragment,
            R.id.Fragment2,
            R.id.Fragment3
        )
    )
    bottomNav = binding.bottomNavigationView
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    bottomNav.setupWithNavController(navController)

}

   override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
     val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
     return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

And your DashboardFragment should look like:

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentDashboardBinding

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_dashboard,container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // start your code here...
   
}
```

*Note:

- bottom nav menu id and fragment id in nav_graph should be same
- in nav_graph check that in first <navigation tag there should be property like app:startDestination="@id/dashboardFragment"

If this doesn't solve your issue then comment to this post with your MainActivity and nav_graph code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem exact problem. I figured out that in my MainActivity.kt, I had both

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

as well as

```
setContentView(binding.root)
```

after setting up view binding, and that's what was causing the problem. After getting rid of the first setContentView(), the navHost worked correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).